# Run a django update but call the save method

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to do the following:

```
asset, _ = Asset.objects.get_or_create(system=item['system'], system_table=item['system_table'], ...)
Asset.objects.filter(pk=asset.pk).update(**item)
```

And also call the `.save()` method? I think I've read somewhere that you can run an update on the actual instance and not go through the `objects` manager. How would that be done? Currently I'm doing the following, which is quite repetitive and inefficient:

```
a = Asset.objects.filter(pk=asset.pk).update(**item)
a.save()
```

Comment: Why do you want/need to call the `save()` method? `.update()` executes a DB query and won't trigger any signals. Why not just iterate over the queryset and call `.save()` for each result?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have special code in the `save` method that I need to trigger whenever an object is updated (even if it's through the `update(...)`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code in the `save` method? Can you not just iterate over the queryset and call save for every result? If this code must be called even on an `update` maybe creating a custom manager that prevented calling update?

Comment: If you already have the `asset` object, why are you calling `filter()`?

Comment: @David542 Then call `get()` instead of `filter()` and then `save()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just added an update to it if that helps.

Comment: There is no point of using get_or_create here as you could rathere use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create instead

Comment: @iklinac my django version doesn't have that method yet.

Comment: Well I would strongly suggest for security reasons to pass onto at least LTS version that would be 2.2. update_or_create is available from version 1.7 which is 6 years old

Comment: What is `item`? I assume it is a dict. Is that right? Have you looked at using a form for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to just call `save()` directly. You will need to call `get()` instead of `filter()`, though.

```
Asset.objects.get(pk=asset.pk).save(update_fields=item)
```

This isn't a problem since your existing `filter()` is guaranteed to return a queryset with at most one `Asset` anyway. You just have to be sure that the given `pk` actually exists or wrap the `get()` call in a `try...except` block.

But...since you already have the `Asset` instance in `asset`, there's no reason to waste time with a DB query. Just call `save` directly on the object you have:

```
asset.save(update_fields=item)
```

Comment: Oh that solves my issue. I didn't know you could pass kwargs like that to the `save` method.

Comment: @David542 You can pass kwargs with the `**` syntax to **any** python method. This is not a Django thing.

Comment: well of course, I meant that passing the `kwargs` to the `save` method actually updates the database with that.

Comment: @David542 Oh wait...I see what you mean...one sec

Comment: @Code-Apprentice passing relevant fields, ie, "model fields" to `save()` method won't work

Comment: as you do .save(a=5,b=4) you are passing kwargs ( keyword arguments)

Comment: @David542 You're right. You need to use `update_fields` instead.

Comment: @David542 Okay, I updated my answer to use `update_fields=items`. Your custom `save()` will either need to call `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` or handle `update_fields` itself.

Comment: @JPG Yup, my bad. I think my recent edit will do the job, though.

Comment: Not really, I was expecting something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67496468/8283848)

Comment: @JPG Please unaccept my answer since it is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not authored to do that since I'm not the person who asked the question. Definitely, @David542 can do that

Comment: @JPG My bad. I thought you were the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the ***`asset`*** object, you can just make use of it.

```py
# assuming that you have a `Asset` object in `asset` variable, somehow

item = {"foo": "foo-value"}
for field, value in items.items():
    setattr(asset, field, name)
asset.save()
```

You can also specify the **`update_fields`** parameter of `save()` method as

```
asset.save(update_fields=list(item.keys()))
```